# Assign value to array based on row criteria true/false

Tags: f#

Hi i would like to achieve something like

Arr.[(rows where criteria is met),K] <- 1

How do I write this in F#?

I.e I have an array 
let x= [|0.0..10.0|]

Arr`s number of rows is equal to x.length and the criteria could be rows where x==10.0, the index 9. Not confined to be only a single index that matches the criteria.

Stig

Comment: What does this mean: "rows where x==10.0, the index 9". Is this index the same what "K" stands for in Your Arr?

Comment: K is a constant, column "K", the second dimension. No, the "==" is the equality/comparison-operator in R. I have one array x where I`m looking for the indexes, and then I want to set the rows with the corresponding indexes/rows, and column K, to 1.0. My example is a bit wrong, I should have had the array from 1 to 10 for the index to be 9. In my example x=10 for index 10. (0-based)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x |> Array.iteri (fun i x ->
    if x = 10.0 then Arr.[i] <- 1)
```

Comment: thanks!

     x|> Array.iteri (fun i x -> if x=boundaryKnots.[1] then Bmat.[i,(K-1)] <- 1.0)